# Delete a blank row below specific data

Tags: excel, vba

I need a script (Excel VBA) that will delete a **blank** line in a spreadsheet **below** wherever 'Monday' appears - can anyone help?

In the example below I need the Mondays to be in together (no blank rows)

```
name    Monday 02 05 16

name    Monday 02 05 16

name    Monday 02 05 16

name    Monday 02 05 16  
name    Tuesday 03 05 16  
name    Tuesday 03 05 16
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Maybe you could also post your code (edit it into your question).

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
Option Explicit

Sub MAIN()
Dim cell As Range
Dim mondaysAddress As String

With Worksheets("MyWS") '<~~ replace "MyWS" with you actual worksheet name    
    For Each cell In .Columns("A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlTextValues)'<~~ replace "A" with whatever column cells you must search the word "Monday" in
        If InStr(UCase(cell.Value), "MONDAY") Then
            If IsEmpty(cell.Offset(1)) Then mondaysAddress = mondaysAddress & cell.Offset(1).Address & ","
        End If
    Next cell
    mondaysAddress = Left(mondaysAddress, Len(mondaysAddress) - 1)
    Range(mondaysAddress).EntireRow.Delete
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: you are welcome. If my answer fulfilled your question then please mark it as accepted. thank you